# Ps4 not turning on and shuts down mid game

Tags: ps4, controllers

My PS4 power sensors don't work and haven't for quite some time now so I just turn it on using the PS button on the controller but lately my PS4 has been shutting down mid game and turning it on using my controller doesn't seem to work anymore, the controller just lights up for a few seconds then turns off. What's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I bought a pretty cheap controller off of Amazon and this was one of the many problems with the controller. Unless you know how to repair a ps4 controller you either have to buy a new one or send off to be repaired.

Comment: I bought the controller from sony a few months bck and it seems to be working properly besides that